# Migrating from a Windows client/server to Linux client/server environment

Tags: linux, windows

In my company, all PCs and Servers run Windows.

I'm not an expert in Linux and Unix stuff, but I believe it's possible to change the whole thing to Linux. If we don't have any applications that are mission critical, why wouldn't I change to Linux for the benefits (secure, extra configurable and highly increase the amount of knowledge about computing )?

What is the scenario or the directions or the steps those are required to do such a thing? What is the equivalent of an Active Directory Domain in the Linux world?

I know some stuff about OpenLDAP, NIS, Debian and CentOS, but I know I miss many things, if not why I'm asking in the first place...

Comment: You really need some more details about your *current* requirements before you can even think about building a case for such a migration.

Comment: Step 1: Analyze your requirements. Step 2: Determine if such a thing is feasible. There is no possible way we can perform either of these steps for you on a Q&A site - this is a huge project that would require a consulting *team* to even begin to approach doing right...

Comment: "I'm not an expert in Linux and Unix stuff, but I believe it's possible to change the whole thing to Linux." Whoah.  Right.  To me that says.. "I'm no expert in brain surgery, but a frontal lobotomy should be easy with a Dewalt drill".

Comment: Completely changing an infrastructure without putting in more thought past "well it can be done" does not mean a.) you should do it or b.) that it's a good idea.

Comment: All we need is just an Office, adobe reader and writer, web browser, DVD writer, files and folders share, printers share, email client and some tools to make simple graphics, that's it for the clients PC's, and for the server something like ISA server, central users and group management system like active directory, controlling users and groups permissions and privileges, what to do?

Comment: Last I checked, Adobe doesn't make reader or Acrobat Pro for Linux and there's no direct analog to Active Directory in Linux. There are a lot of different ways to put all of the different pieces together to get what you want, but there's no single bundles package like AD. There's a reason that Microsoft owns so much of the business desktop/laptop market. They made really good management tools that have low barriers to entry. Don't you think if there were comparably easy Linux solutions that people would stop buying Microsoft?

Comment: @cwigmer.wdm What to do? ***Really analyze your requirements.*** You need to talk to your users, you can't just throw a list together like that. It's woefully incomplete. (Just two examples: "simple graphics" - so if I give your staff an MSPaint equivalent they'd be happy? ; "Office" - so it has to read/write MS Office documents, or can I give you something functionally equivalent but totally incompatible?) -- this is NOT a change that is made lightly - preparation can take a year or more in small companies...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, this is a terrible idea. If you don't know how to manage Linux and you don't understand the implications, you shouldn't be doing this. An operating system is only as secure as someone that knows how to manage it. If you're familiar with Windows and unfamiliar with Linux, then the odds are that you'll be much worse-off with Linux while you learn.

Also, keep in mind that configuration management is handled much differently. You'll need to learn something like Puppet, Chef, or radmind instead of using tools like Group Policy or SCCM.

Basically, you'll need an authorization database to replace AD. You can use any number of LDAP servers out there. Go do some research.

You'll need productivity applications. Does OpenOffice meet all of your requirements?

You'll need to **train your employees**. Are you OK with the workflow interruption that is going to happen as you uproot their entire technology infrastructure?

Are you going to learn things like Zimbra/Dovecot/Postfix/Sendmail instead of Exchange? Are you going to learn to manage Apache instead of IIS?

---

If you have a compelling business case, then sure, go for it. But do your research. There's nothing inherently more secure or better about Windows or Linux. It's only as good as the person managing it and the quality of that management will drop sharply as you learn a whole new suite of tools.

Comment: First of all, Thank u ALL so much for your answers and comments, secondly, I know it will take us a long time to achieve such a thing, but it was a discussion between me and my boss, he asked me if is it possible or not after the management meeting about the company current situation. but after all i got some really very good tips and hints about what we will face and what the migration will cost to be done. THANKS.

Comment: No problem. If you feel like this answered your question, you should click the green check mark next to this answer so other can see that it helped you :)